# Avoid duplicates in the gif Store - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[image]I am creating a gif store using angular. I have a page with search input , when i write a gif name into it a giphy search api is called and it returns the gifs based on name. At the same time i have created a user Store where i am saving the gifs via localStorage. The gifs are object with url and id. I want to check if the gif coming from giphy api is already present in localStorage it should not be added in user Store(localStorage).

Below is the code

User-Gif.component -
OnSeachClick method returns gifs from giphy api.

```
onSearchClick() : void {
    this.gs.searchGif(this.searchInput,this.defaultLimit).subscribe(res => {
      this.gifData = res.data;
    })
  }
```

addToStore method stores the gifs returned from giphy api in localStorage-

```
 addToStore(): void {
    let addGif= new Array<GifUrl>();
  
    this.gifData.forEach((i:any) => {
      addGif.unshift({
        id: i.id,
        url: i.images.original.url,
        date: new Date()
      })
      localStorage.setItem(this.searchInput.toUpperCase(),JSON.stringify(addGif));
   })
  
    this.getDataInStore();
    this.gifData = [];
    addGif=[];
    this.searchInput = '';
  }
```

getDataInStore methods gets the gifs from localStorage -

```
 getDataInStore():void {
    this.gifUrl=[];
    if(Object.keys(localStorage)) {
      Object.keys(localStorage).forEach((key:string)=> {
       let keyData:any[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key) || '')
        this.gifUrl.push(...keyData);
     })
    }
  }
```

User-gif.html -

```
    <div class="userStore">
        <app-user-store [gifData]="gifUrl" (filteredData)="getFilteredData($event)" (sortedData)="sortByDate()"
            (resetSearch)="resetData()">
        </app-user-store>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have added a simple way to do that. You need to use `Set` to prevent from duplicate items

Comment: Are you OK to have the same image stored on two different keys? Like if you search "Hi" and "Hello" you might have the same GIF stored on different Keys.
Or should the be completly unique?

Comment: @Zerotwelve No it has to be unique. Or we can try like while searching itself we need to perform a checkDuplicate operation and then return result according. I cant understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

solution should be pretty simple:

```js
isInLocalStorage(key:string):boolean{
  return localStorage.getItem(key) !== null;
}
```

before adding the element, check if it's already present

--- EDIT ---

based on your feedback, what you want to do is to check if an image is already present in your localstorage, you need to create a function to check that and return a boolean value.

first you need to iterate trough all you key and parse the data. You already done that in your code example.
Now you have to check if the element is present, you can do it like this.

```js
let keyData:any[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key) || '[]')
// newElementId is the id of the image you try to add, i.E. "888R35MJTmDxOfRzf5" 
return keyData.findIndex(data => data.id === newElementId) > -1;
```

Comment: Hi, i have added the image of my localStorage in the question(sorry it got added before the question.). I am storing a key against that key i have value in key,value pair. Also, i am saving the id but still i am not able to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this condition: `if(Object.keys(localStorage))`
always evaluates to true. When localStorage is empty, Object.keys will return an empty array, which is 'truthy': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy.

Regards your question: you're currently storing the GifUrls in local storage as an array, and your 'key' for accessing localStorage is the search term.

It would be much more efficient to store the gifs in localStorage with the gif ID as the key.

By storing gifs in an array, Angular will need to search potentially every GifUrl array for the duplicate gif - a gif returned from searching 'like' could also be returned by searching 'love' for example, and Angular won't "know" beforehand which GifUrl arrays to search - it will have to check them all, each time a new search is made.

By storing each Gif by ID, checking for a duplicate will instead be a matter of checking by calling `localStorage.getItem(gifID)`.

Comment: Hi, i have added the image of my localStorage in the question(sorry it got added before the question.). I am storing a key against that key i have value in key,value pair. Also, i am saving the id but still i am not able to remove the duplicates.

Comment: edited my answer based on your feedback

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Set` in order to prevent from duplicate items before setting into the `localStorage`. something like this:

```
this.gifData.forEach((i:any) => {
      addGif.unshift({
        id: i.id,
        url: i.images.original.url,
        date: new Date()
      })
//This is new line that You want
let uniqueItems = Array.from(new Set(addGif));
      
localStorage.setItem(this.searchInput.toUpperCase(),JSON.stringify(uniqueItems));
   })
```

Comment: I doubt this will prevent dups though. Set only works on primitives if you need uniques..

Comment: This solution wont work. As you can see in the image above. For key 'Hi' 10 records are saved. So when i will add key 'Bye' before adding i need to check all ids of key 'Hi' with all ids of key 'Bye' and delete the id that matched.